# How to make Unity button to change certain content in a ScrollView

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my training app, I have two scrollviews, one with 4 buttons and one with 16 buttons, which are also defined as sprites in my UI Manager.
My question is how to make a button1 from the first scrollview on click to display only the first 4 buttons(sprites) from the second scrollview, button 2 to display the second 4 buttons in the second scrollview and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a list of 16 buttons, have 4 lists of 4 buttons. Then each button in your first panel displays the entirety of *one* list.

Heck, you don't even need to rise the same ScrollView. You could have 4 scroll views and the buttons in the first set just enable one of those 4 secondary scroll views (disabling the rest).